# GDB crashes at start (internal error: follow_die_offset)

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have a small C++ project under Linux. When I try to debug the executable with gdb I get the following error:

```
../../gdb/dwarf2read.c:16760: internal-error: follow_die_offset:
Assertion 'dwarf2_per_objfile->reading_partial_symbols' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

I have strongly simplified the project to the following code and still get the same error:

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_H_
#define B_H_

#include <vector>
class B {
public:
    B();
    std::vector<double> p;
};

#endif /* B_H_ */
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
B::B() {}
```

D.h:

```
#ifndef D_H_
#define D_H_

#include "E.h"

class D: public E {
public:
    D();
};

#endif /* D_H_ */
```

D.cpp:

```
#include "D.h"

D::D() : E() {}
```

E.h:

```
#ifndef E_H_
#define E_H_

#include <functional>

class E {

public:
    void set(const std::function<double(void)>& f);
    std::function<double(void)> e;

};

#endif /* E_H_ */
```

E.cpp:

```
#include "E.h"

void E::set(const std::function<double(void)>& f) {
    e = f;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main() {}
```

makefile:

```
all: Test

%.o: %.cpp
    icpc -c -std=c++11 -g -o $@ $<

Test: main.o D.o E.o B.o
    icpc -std=c++11  -o $@ $^

clean: 
    rm -f D.o E.o B.o Test main.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

The error occurs if I do:

```
gdb Test
```

and then invoke

```
run
```

in the gdb CLI.

My system:

Open Suse 12.3, 64bit

icpc --version:

```
icpc (ICC) 15.0.1 20141023
```

icpc -v:

```
icpc version 15.0.1 (gcc version 4.7.0 compatibility)
```

gdb --version:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) SUSE (7.5.1-2.1.1)
```

gcc --version:

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]
```

I have no idea what is wrong with the given code and why the debugger crashes. For example if I comment out the constructor of class B (which does nothing and should be equivalent to the default constructor) the error does not appear anymore.

Comment: If that version of Intel System Studio includes its own gdb, can you try it?

Comment: I think I did but I am not sure what I need to do. Simply take the gdb executable from the intel_composer bin-folder ?

Comment: In the version I have, there's a `debuggervars.sh` file in the system studio bin directory. If that directory in your search path, type `source debuggervars.sh`, and it will set up your environment so you can then run Intel's debugger by typing `gdb-ia`.

Comment: @user1304680 Have you had any luck with this, or filed a bug report? I can reproduce this on Linux Mint 17.1 (based on Ubuntu 14.04) 64 bit, icpc version 15.0.0, GDB version 7.7.1, and also Intel debugger (`gdb-ia`) version 7.7-8.0.524.

Comment: Also, I discovered that if I change the order of input files to `B.o D.o E.o main.o`, then then neither `gdb` or `gdb-ia` crash.

Comment: I just cross-posted to the Intel Developer Zone forums https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/540685

Comment: No I hadn't filed a report yet

Answer (score 2):

See this thread: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/540685 -- it seems to be an issue in gdb, fixed in 7.9. **UPDATE** I upgraded gdb to 7.9 and the problem really went away, for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea what is wrong with the given code and why the debugger crashes.

There is likely nothing wrong with your code, but your compiler may be generating invalid DWARF debug info, and your somewhat *old* GDB certainly has a bug dealing with that.

Note that you are using very new `icpc` with old GDB, so this isn't very surprising.

Your first step should be to build current GDB (7.8.1) and check whether it still has a problem.

In the unlikely case that it does, you should report it in GDB [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla).

As a workaround, you may also try building your sources with GCC instead of ICC.

Comment: I guess thats true, the error also goes away with older icc versions. I will try with newer gdb as well.

Comment: Then you can probably at least file a bugreports (together with testcase).